# How to reorder rows in R data.table given a specific row order

Tags: r, data.table

Given a data.table and vector like

```
fruit.inventory <- data.table(fruit=c('apples', 'oranges', 'bananas'), count=c(5, 16, 23))
fruit.request <- c('pineapple', 'peaches', 'oranges', 'apples')
```

How can I get back this

```
# fruit  count
# oranges  16
# apples 5
```

I know this can be accomplished with something  like this

```
setkey(fruit.inventory, fruit)
fruit.subset <- fruit.inventory[fruit.request]
fruit.subset <- fruit.subset[complete.cases(fruit.subset)]
```

However, I'd like to use something shorter like

```
fruit.subset <- fruit.inventory[fruit %in% fruit.request]
```

but it does not respect the order of the original vector. I know there are a few other workarounds but I keep thinking there has to be a simpler way to do this than what I have above.

Comment: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/pull/4340 this PR will allow to re-order in-place easily using any customer order

Answer (score 3):

Here is another option using an inner join:

```
fruit.inventory[.(fruit.request), on=.(fruit), nomatch=0L]
```

Comment: This was the syntax I was looking for. Looks the most concise in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```r
fruit.inventory[order(na.exclude(match(fruit.inventory$fruit, fruit.request)))]
```

which gives

```r
     fruit count
1: oranges    16
2:  apples     5
```

The code above can be written using package `dplyr` as

```r
fruit.inventory %>%
  pull(fruit) %>%
  match(fruit.request) %>%
  na.exclude() %>%
  order() %>%
  fruit.inventory[.]
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion might be an overkill but it's not very difficult to implement.

I always have a few functions at hand an `merge_keeping_order` is one of them

```
merge_keeping_order <- function(x,y,...){
    x$orderId <- 1:nrow(x)
    a <- merge(x,y,...)
    a <- a[order(a$orderId),]
    a$orderId <- NULL
    a
}
```

Then all you have to do is to convert you vector to a data.table as below

```
 merge_keeping_order(as.data.table(fruit.request),
 fruit.inventory,by.x="fruit.request",by.y="fruit")


##    fruit.request count
## 1:       oranges    16
## 2:        apples     5
```